# Meta Tag: Top-7

Tags: discussion, tags, top-7

Noticed someone added the tag [top-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/top-7) to a few things. Wondering if that serves some purpose I don't know of.

https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/top-7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely related to the recent [Cartaino](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4/robert-cartaino) blog post, "[The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)" which looks at the top seven things a StackExchange site should ask itself if it wants to live and grow with its community.